# Can't run my project even if there are no errors

Tags: android-studio

I have just opened my project in Android Studio. 
The run icon in the top-right corner of my window is unclickable, so I can't run my project. If i try to build the project it does not display any error.

Here is the screenshot of Android Studio:
[image: My screenshot]

Could you please help me out? Thank you in advance for your help and your patience.

Comment: Are there any options available under the "Run" menu?

Comment: @JohnPerry Just an 'Edit Configurations...' option